# Percentage calculation

Tags: c#, calculator

What would be the best way to refactor following methods?

```
private string CalcualtePercentageDifference(string temp1, string temp2)
    {

        double number1 = ParseDouble(temp1);
        double number2 = ParseDouble(temp2);
        double percentageDifference = 0;

         if (number1 == 0 || number2 == 0)
         {
             return "0 %";
         }

        if ((number1 >= number2) && number1 > 0 && number2 > 0)
        {
            double tempNumber = number2*100/number1;
            Math.Abs(percentageDifference = 100 - tempNumber);
        }
        if ((number2 >= number1) && number1 > 0 && number2 > 0)
        {
            double tempNumber = number1*100/number2;
            Math.Abs(percentageDifference = 100 - tempNumber);
        }
        if (number1 < 0 && number2 > 0)
        {
            double tempNumber = (number2 + Math.Abs(number1))/Math.Abs(number1);
            Math.Abs(percentageDifference = 100 - tempNumber);
        }

        if (number2 < 0 && number1 > 0)
        {
            double tempNumber = (number1 + Math.Abs(number2))/Math.Abs(number2);
            Math.Abs(percentageDifference = 100 - tempNumber);
        }
        if (number1 < 0 && number2 < 0)
        {
            number1 = Math.Abs(number1);
            number2 = Math.Abs(number2);

            if ((number1 >= number2))
            {
                double tempNumber = number2 * 100 / number1;
                Math.Abs(percentageDifference = 100 - tempNumber);
            }
            if ((number2 >= number1))
            {
                double tempNumber = number1 * 100 / number2;
                Math.Abs(percentageDifference = 100 - tempNumber);
            }
        }


        return Math.Round(percentageDifference) + " %";

    }


    private static double ParseDouble(object value, string valueName = "")
    {
        double outValue = double.NaN;

        try
        {
            outValue = Convert.ToDouble(value);
        }
        catch (FormatException e)
        {
            //We will get here when value contains NumberDecimalSeparator different from this in current culture
            //Convert now using suitable culture
            outValue = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator == ","
                       ? Convert.ToDouble(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                       : Convert.ToDouble(value, new CultureInfo("pl-PL"));
        }
        catch (InvalidCastException)
        {
        }


        return outValue;
    }
```

Comment: Math.Abs(percentageDifference = 100 - tempNumber);  This is uncommon usage and, while it works, I would avoid it.  Use percentageDifference = Math.Abs(100 - tempNumber); instead

Comment: Do you want an accurate calculation or do you just want to refactor these weird calcs? Consider that input values (-30,30) will yield a 98% difference from these calcs! Also wouldn't the difference between zero and a non-zero number be 100%?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some general observations first before I go into my refactored proposal:

1. I would try and use a better parameter naming rather than `temp1`, `temp2`.  To be honest I'm not sure if this is better but perhaps `percentage1`, `percentage2` at least indicates the value is expected to be a percentage.
2. Try and get spelling correct. `CalcualtePercentageDifference` should be `CalculatePercentageDifference`
3. Consistent spacing. Sometimes you have spaces after your if statements sometimes you don't. I personally prefer spaces.
4. `Math.Abs` returns a value. You aren't using that value so the calls to this method make no sense. Either remove it or use the value? For the purpose of this review, I'm going to assume you want to use the value.
5. You have redundant brackets in some of your if statements. Consider removing these.

   ```
   if ((number1 >= number20))
   ```
6. If a variable isn't required in a function, then I would suggest you remove it.

   ```
   private static double ParseDouble(object value)
   ```
7. `ParseDouble` potentially returns `NaN`. I think you can account for that in code without letting general exceptions occur.
8. I'm not sure why you need to swallow the `InvalidCastException`. In fact, is swallowing the exceptions at all what you are after?
   In general I try not to do this, but it can depend on the situation, so perhaps in this case it's ok.

Now for the code:

```
public string CalculatePercentageDifference(string percentage1, string percentage2)
{
    double number1 = ParseDouble(percentage1);
    double number2 = ParseDouble(percentage2);

    if (double.IsNaN(number1) || double.IsNaN(number2))
    {
        return "NaN";
    }

    var percentageDifference = CalculatePercentageDifference(number1, number2);
    return percentageDifference + " %";
}
```

Parse `double` without the additional parameter:

```
private static double ParseDouble(object value)
{
    double outValue = double.NaN;

    try
    {
        outValue = Convert.ToDouble(value);
    }
    catch (FormatException e)
    {
        //We will get here when value contains NumberDecimalSeparator different from this in current culture
        //Convert now using suitable culture
        try
        {
            outValue = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator == ","
                       ? Convert.ToDouble(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                       : Convert.ToDouble(value, new CultureInfo("pl-PL"));
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            // If we still get here then there's something wrong
        }
    }
    catch (InvalidCastException)
    {
    }

    return outValue;
}
```

And the main refactored method:

```
public int CalculatePercentageDifference(double number1, double number2)
{
    if (number1.Equals(0) || number2.Equals(0))
    {
        return 0;
    }

    const double tolerance = 0.000000001;            
    // If numbers are the same then there is no difference
    if (Math.Abs(number1 - number2) < tolerance)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    Func<double, int> percentageDifference = number =>
    {
        var difference = Math.Abs(100 - number);
        return (int) Math.Round(difference);
    };

    Func<double, double, int> differenceHighLow = (numberHigh, numberLow) =>
    {
        var number = numberHigh * 100 / numberLow;

        return percentageDifference(number);
    };

    // Convert to positive numbers if they are both negative
    if (number1 < 0 && number2 < 0)
    {
        number1 = Math.Abs(number1);
        number2 = Math.Abs(number2);
    }

    // At least one of the numbers are positive at this stage
    if (number1 > 0 && number2 > 0)
    {
        return number1 > number2 ? 
            differenceHighLow(number2, number1) : 
            differenceHighLow(number1, number2);
    }

    // One number is a negative but the other is positive
    Func<double, double, int> postiveNegativeDifference = (postiveNumber, negativeNumber) =>
    {
        var tempNumber = (postiveNumber + Math.Abs(negativeNumber)) / Math.Abs(negativeNumber);
        return percentageDifference(tempNumber);
    };

    if (number1 < 0 && number2 > 0)
    {
        return postiveNegativeDifference(number2, number1);
    }

    return postiveNegativeDifference(number1, number2);
}
```

And of course a refactoring wouldn't be anywhere without some unit tests (of course, more would be recommended):

```
[TestMethod]
public void DifferenceBetweenZero_IsZero()
{
    // Arrange
    var model = new _101777_PercentageCalcManyIfs();

    // Act
    var difference = model.CalculatePercentageDifference("0.0", "0.0");

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual("0 %", difference);
}

[TestMethod]
public void DifferenceBetweenNonNumbers_IsNan()
{
    // Arrange
    var model = new _101777_PercentageCalcManyIfs();

    // Act
    var difference = model.CalculatePercentageDifference("a.0", "0.0");

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual("NaN", difference);
}

[TestMethod]
public void DifferenceBetweenTwoPostiveNumbers()
{
    // Arrange
    var model = new _101777_PercentageCalcManyIfs();

    // Act
    var difference = model.CalculatePercentageDifference("5.0", "10.0");

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual("50 %", difference);
}
```

Comment: There is no block like: `if (()number1 >= number20)`

Comment: *`Consistent spacing. Sometimes you have spaces after your if statements sometimes you don't. I prefer personally spaces.`* I can't see any instances of extraneous lines after `if` statements.

Answer (score 5):

Let the operators and the numbers have some space to breathe. Looking at

> ```
> double tempNumber = number2*100/number1;
> ```

it is hard to see that the variable is called `number2`. So by adding some horizontal space will increase the readability like so

```
double tempNumber = number2 * 100 / number1;
```

---

The `if` condition here

> ```
> if ((number2 >= number1) && number1 > 0 && number2 > 0)
> ```

can be simplified by removing the check for `number2 > 0`. If `number2` is greater than or equal to `number1` **and**  `number1` is greater than `0` then for sure `number2` is also greater than `0`.

The same is true for

> ```
> if ((number1 >= number2) && number1 > 0 && number2 > 0)
> ```

---

> ```
>     if (number1 < 0 && number2 < 0)
>     {
>         number1 = Math.Abs(number1);
>         number2 = Math.Abs(number2);
>
>         if ((number1 >= number2))
>         {
>             double tempNumber = number2 * 100 / number1;
>             Math.Abs(percentageDifference = 100 - tempNumber);
>         }
>         if ((number2 >= number1))
>         {
>             double tempNumber = number1 * 100 / number2;
>             Math.Abs(percentageDifference = 100 - tempNumber);
>         }
>     }
> ```

In this construct you are calculating the `percentageDifference` two times if `number1` and `number2` are both `< 0` and are the same. Using an `else if` would skip this.

---

If you would declare `tempNumber`, which by the way is named sub optimal,  instead of `percentageDifference` outside of the `if`'s you could remove a lot of code duplication by calling `Math.Abs(percentageDifference = 100 - tempNumber);` at the end of thr method. In addition why do you use it like this and not like

```
percentageDifference = Math.Abs(100 - tempNumber);
```

which would be more readable.

Answer (score 5):

There's a much simpler way than many `if-else` loops:

```
if (number1 === 0 || number2 === 0) {
    return 0;
}
if (number1 > number2) {
    double tempNumber = number2;
    number2 = number1;
    number1 = tempNumber;
}
double difference = Math.Abs(100 - ((number1 / number2) * 100));
return Math.Round(difference) + " %";
```

By testing for the larger variable, you can escape the need for two 'which-is-larger' loops.

---

A few things to point out about your code:

- `valueName` is unused.
- `catch (InvalidCastException)`: there's probably not a reason to swallow this, but either way.
- `string temp1, string temp2`: they're not `temp`orary values, don't name them like that.
- `number1*100/number2`: add some whitespace and even brackets to clearly show which values affect each other, *don't let [BODMAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) sort out your mess for you*!

Comment: Regarding your observation about the `InvalidCastException`, it falls under the [Boneheaded exception](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx) category: "That argument is null, that typecast is bad, that index is out of range, you're trying to divide by zero – these are all problems that you could have prevented very easily in the first place, so prevent the mess in the first place rather than trying to clean it up."

Comment: And the solution would be to change the type of the parameter `value` from `object` to `string` (since it'll always be a string anyway), and then using `double.TryParse` instead of `Double.Convert`. You won't need to catch `FormatException`s either.